# "Девушка была некрасивой". Правописание частицы НЕ

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные

**Девушка была некрасивой.**
Здесь будет слитно писаться прилагательное с частицей "не" или возможен и раздельный вариант написания? (Подразумевается противопоставление.)

Answer (score 3):

Девушка была **некрасивой** (= невзрачной, малопривлекательной). Слитное написание НЕ, утверждение признака, возможность замены синонимом без НЕ.

Раздельное написание: Девушка **не была красивой**. Здесь отрицание признака.

Противопоставление: Девушка была **не красивой**, а просто симпатичной.